# When spark-shell launch, It has RuntimeException for SimpleUserGroupsMapping

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I install HDFS, YARN through Ambari and try to deploy spark on yarn.

But When I execute follow script, Spark has error

How to deploy spark on yarn.
Would you mind explaining how to deploy spark on yarn step by step?

I set HADOOP_CONF_DIR, YARN_CONF_DIR in spark-env.sh and spark.master in spark-defaults.conf.

**execute script**

```
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.security.SimpleUserGroupsMapping not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:763)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:621)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2136)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2136)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2136)
        at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.<init>(SparkIMain.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter.<init>(SparkILoop.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createInterpreter(SparkILoop.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:949)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.security.SimpleUserGroupsMapping not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2098)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.security.SimpleUserGroupsMapping not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2072)
        ... 34 more
16/02/19 22:07:20 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/02/19 22:07:20 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the class is present in your hadoop classpath.

```
find $HADOOP_HOME/* -name *.jar -print |xargs grep "org.apache.hadoop.security.SimpleUserGroupsMapping" -0
```

if present then check if the class is present in spark distribution

```
grep  "org.apache.hadoop.security.SimpleUserGroupsMapping" $SPARK_HOME/lib/*
```

If the jar is present in hadoop distribution try copy it to $SPARK_HOME/lib/.

If none of the above works try changing

```
hadoop.security.group.mapping org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback
```

in core-site.xml and restart hadoop and spark.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was great solution!!